# "Whitelabel Error Page" Got this error while building from source

Tags: thingsboard

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat Nov 11 23:14:39 SGT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

I was building this from the source and got this error. Anyone faced this error before and how to solve this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when SVG files have XML content in it such as text. Convert all entities in svg to one object and used optimized svg option and then rebuild. It should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi, How to redirect to custome login page to thingsboard.io/home using auth/login API, Please if you have knowledge can you share with us.